# Firebase hosting: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found

Tags: firebase, next.js, next.js13

I have a Nextjs app hosted with firebase. I have been using it normally for months. But now, I simply can't deploy it anymore. It might be related with me updating firebase-tools, but even downgrading now, it does not work.
I also deleted the nextjs server function, and it does recreate it properly. The error just comes after that.

This is the message I get on deployment:

[deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnlYt.jpg)

This is the debug-log:[debug-log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm5P5.jpg)

And this is my firebase.json and .firebasesrc. Which I don't think it's the cause of the problem, since it was working before.

```
"hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "asia-east1"
    }
  }
```

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "******"
  }
}
```

I have tried reinstalling and restart the project from scratch, but it still does not work. I also tried to add "site" and "target" to firebase.json.
I have read some topics with similar problem, but those solutions did not work for me.
I am not sure if it is some instability with firebase.

If you guys can figure it out, that would be awesome.
Thank you!!

I tried to deploy my nextjs app to firebase hosting, but got this error instead: Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is going through the same problem, it is being discussed over here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6110

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.